# Average on column grouped by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL server with a table myTable which has the following columns:

```
nid            int(10)   unsigned
temperature    float     unsigned
timestamp      int(10)   unsigned
```

This table has about 300.000 records and keeps growing every day. In order to handle this amount of data I would like to find some SQL queries that could provide me interval-based averages such as "Hourly average", "Daily average", etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: `group by` and the date/time functions come to mind.

Comment: Also, look at partitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer. I order to get the daily average I can use:

```
 SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS Date, 
        AVG(temperature) AS AvgTemp
 FROM   `myTable`
 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```

In order to get the hourly average (for each day), I use:

```
 SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS Date,
        HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS Hour, 
        AVG(temperature) as AvgTemp
 FROM   `myTable`
 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)),
          HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```